# Mongodb geospatial index TopoJSON

Tags: mongodb, topojson

How to create a geospatial index for TopoJSON formatted data using mongodb? 
using GeoJson formatted data can easily create a geospatial index but topojson i cann't found.

Comment: If you are asking "what forms of GeoJSON are supported?" by MongoDB geospatial indexing then they are [listed here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson/). Not every type in the GeoJSON spec is even supported ( ie Feature is not supported ), so certainly any custom library formats are also not going to be supported. You can store what you want, but you will be relying on external processing, and not the database methods that require an index.

Comment: No, i ask can i create a geospatial index for TopoJSON formatted data such as 2dsphere?  i know i can create index and query for geojson but for topojson  i don't know.

Comment: You might want to re-read what I just said, because your response basically reads "No, I want to use a geospatial index for data types that it does not support".

Comment: @FarizAgayev, did you find any solution? I'm also searching solution for similar kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

mongoDB doesn't support TopoJSON. There is an open ticket asking to support it since 2017.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30522